# TCL : Is there any command to get package location and procedure names inside that package?

Tags: tcl

Is there any command to trace the package file location and to display the procedures that are defined in that package?
If this capability is present, that would be a great help in searching and quick debugging when the programmer has to maintain huge number of packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have dealt with a similar problem before. There is no magic in getting your answer, just a lot of elbow grease. Here is my suggestion:

1. Before importing a package, record the list of name spaces and commands
2. Import the package in question
3. Record the list of name spaces and commands again
4. From the "before" and "after" lists, we can derive a list of new name spaces and commands

#### Discussion

- I am using an array `stat` to ease debugging: during development of the code, I can just `parray stat` to debug
- A package such as `csv` neatly puts new commands in a name space of the same name: `::csv`, whereas others such as `Tcx` puts things in the global name space. We need to address both cases

#### Caveats

- A package might import other packages, which throw off the counts (of name spaces and commands)
- I don't know the differences between `info commands` and `info procs`. I always use the former
- The procedure `packageStatistics` requires a valid package name. Give it an invalid name, unexpected behaviors will happen

#### The Code

```
package require struct::set 

proc packageStatistics {packageName} {
    # Record "before" statistics
    set stat(ns,before) [namespace children]
    set stat(cmd,before) [info commands]

    # Now, import the package in question
    set stat(version) [package require $packageName]

    # Record "after" statistics
    set stat(location) [package ifneeded $packageName $stat(version)]
    set stat(ns,after) [namespace children]
    set stat(cmd,after) [info commands]

    # Report package name, version and location
    puts "Package: $packageName version $stat(version)"
    puts "Location:"
    puts "$stat(location)"

    # Show a list of extra commands in the global namespace
    puts "Commands:"
    set stat(cmd,new) [lsort [struct::set difference $stat(cmd,after) $stat(cmd,before)]]
    foreach cmd $stat(cmd,new) {
        puts "- $cmd"
    }

    # Show a list of extra commands in each of the extra namespace
    set stat(ns,new) [lsort [struct::set difference $stat(ns,after) $stat(ns,before)]]
    foreach ns $stat(ns,new) {
        foreach cmd [info commands ${ns}::*] {
            puts "- $cmd"
        }
    }
}

packageStatistics csv
```

#### The Output

```
Package: csv version 0.7.2
Location:
source /System/Library/Tcl/tcllib1.12/csv/csv.tcl
Commands:
- ::csv::writematrix
- ::csv::split
- ::csv::Split
- ::csv::writequeue
- ::csv::join
- ::csv::read2matrix
- ::csv::read2queue
- ::csv::split2matrix
- ::csv::Split2matrix
- ::csv::split2queue
- ::csv::joinlist
- ::csv::report
- ::csv::joinmatrix
- ::csv::iscomplete
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any command that answers your question directly. However,

```
package ifneeded <packageName> <packageVersion>
```

will tell you the commands that are executed in order to pull in the package, which will often include a `source` command letting you work out where the package sources are located.

As to working out which procs are defined in a package, the best way I've found of doing this is to do `info procs` to work out what procs you have defined before requiring the package, the require the package, repeat the `info procs` command and determine what's been added. Klunky, I know, but it works.

Comment: That's approximately it. When using a package, it's considered good practice to just use the documented public API. When creating a package, it's considered good practice to not pollute the global namespace with any command that is not part of the documented public API (and probably to put even the documented parts in their own namespace, though that's not mandatory).

Comment: You can get the possible versions of a package — there may be many — with `package versions <packageName>`.